# Unable to import airpush package to android project

Tags: android, airpush

I have downloaded the required SDK from Airpush site. Added the jar to `libs` folder and added the jar to build path. Still I am not able to import its package

```
import com.package.name.AdListener;  
import com.package.name.Prm;
```

when I try to import the above  i get `The import com.package.name.Prm cannot be resolved` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse? because If you are using Android Studio you need to be sure that you have this line of code in your build.gradle. " compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') "

Comment: I am using eclipse, the strange thing is there is no `Prm.class` in the sdk

Comment: Ok, Try doing the clean and build in your project.

Comment: Did that.. Can I use the jar that came in the demo project

Answer (score 0):

try adding it to `lib` folder instead - right click on the jar file > build path > add to build path

Than right click on the project > properties > java build path > libraries folder > expand all and make sure you see you jar listed, if not - add it manually.

clean & build
run